# WSO2 Analytics with ansible in a distributed environment

Tags: ansible, wso2

Please

I'm currently working in a distributed API Manager and Analytics environment to be set through ansible scripts

I need to run analytics balanced through 2 IPs

In my project structure I have the following:
Ansible-vm/ansible-apim/roles/apim-analytics-worker/templates/carbon-home/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml.j2

and in this yaml the following content:
baseUrl: https://localhost:9643

When I try to connect in Analytics :
https://my-host-ip:9643/analytics-dashboard

It tries to redirect it to localhost

I have read the documentation:

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#step-5-configure-apim-idp-client

How can I change the baseUrl so that when I ran the ansible script it reflects properly in both distributed environment IPs ?

Thks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the baseUrl property in the deployment.yaml in dashboard profile.

```
baseUrl: https://yourIp:9643
```

Most of the cases, this baseUrl will be the externally exposed hostname.